# Recording, Taking Snap Shot with HTTP Live streaming video running MPMoviePlayerController in iOS

Tags: ios, video

I am working with an iOS application in which i have play HTTP Live streaming videos. So, i went through some tutorials in the internet and some how i have played HTTP live streaming videos in MPMoviePlayerController in iOS.

But I have another problem with that i have to take snap shot of running streaming video in iOS and i have to record the live streaming video. I searched in the internet. I really did not find any good tutorial. I have to finish it with this two days. So please help me with it.

When i was trying take screen shot, i tried with thumbnailImageAtTime:moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime
                                             timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact, but it is able to get a thumbnail only for the local files not for the streaming video. And i did not find any source to record live streaming video. please help me with this. I'll be really very grateful to you.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: tried using AVPlayer? AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
            CGImageRef thumb = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.0, 1.0)
                                                      actualTime:NULL
                                                           error:NULL];

Comment: Did you get this working? I am after similar functionality and I tried copyCGImageAtTime() but its not working for me