# Intercepting video frames in an HTTP Live Streaming client on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, video, http-live-streaming

In an iPhone app that plays live video from a server via HTTP Live Streaming, is it possible to access decoded video frames after decoding?

As far as I can see `AVPlayer`, `MPMoviePlayer`, and `CoreVideo` do not seem to provide a callback to notify the app that an individual frame has been decoded.

My question is similar to "[Record HTTP Live Streaming Video To File While Watching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671705/record-http-live-streaming-video-to-file-while-watching)", except I'm not necessarily interested in full DVR functionality. The one answer there suggests a server-side solution and is vague about the possibility of a client-side solution. It's also similar to "[Recording, Taking Snap Shot with HTTP Live streaming video running MPMoviePlayerController in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757245/recording-taking-snap-shot-with-http-live-streaming-video-running-mpmovieplayer)" except that I don't require a solution to work with `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using "AVPlayerItemVideoOutput" like this:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
                           (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey : @YES };
myOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:options];
myOutput.suppressesPlayerRendering = NO;
[myOutput requestNotificationOfMediaDataChangeWithAdvanceInterval:1];
[myOutput setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[playerItem addOutput:myOutput];
```

I've done it in several of my projects.. Take care and good luck!

FYI: `(AVPlayerItem *playerItem;)`

/Anders.